# Is Command Pattern Applicable here?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, command-pattern

I've a value object(VO). One of the field/property is 'sourceKey' that holds a string value.

> For Example:
>   String sourceKey1 = "cust12/proj1/site1/images/somefile.JPG"
>   String sourceKey2 = "cust12/area1/site1/images/somefile.JPG"

Now I need to kinda transform this sourceKey and build up a destination key by first breaking the source key by'/' and then:
- replace cust12 by calling customer service - find customer by Id 12 and replace cust12 by customer name in the dest key.
- similarly to replace proj1 - call the project service , find project by id 1 and replace proj1 by the project name.
- and so on..

So to achieve this in a clean manner, I thought of writing commands  - each command for fetching an object by calling the appropriate service(customerService, projectService etc). And then at the client level just parse the sourceString and build up a list of commands to be executed and then finally build up a destination key using the commands list.

Am I thinking in the right direction? Is command pattern the clean/OO way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Command Pattern is not suited to this problem. From an OOP perspective, I would start by modeling the source key as an `Object` rather than a `String`, to avoid [stringly-typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) programming.

It looks like a `SourceKey` object would have dependencies on `CustomerService` and `ProjectService`, and would contain five fields, which it can combine into a `String` as necessary. In other words, try encapsulating the `String` transformation logic into its own `Object`.